# Is it ethical to remove my answer if a lot of comments belong to it?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, etiquette

If I want to remove my answer, but I see a lot of comments belonging to that, what is the ethical way to remove that answer? Should I keep the comments somehow?

Comment: Why do you want to remove your answer in the first place? In any case, comments are second class citizens, if you are set in removing your answer, you shouldn't really worry about the comments.

Comment: Because reading the comments I found out that it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @SzilágyiDonát - [Don't just retag questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/207777/szilagyi-donat?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Instead also improve the body

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Comments are second class citizens, as Yannis points out.

If the comments made you aware that  your answer is wrong, they have served their purpose by making you delete your answer.

If you think someone else might repeat the mistake you made in your answer, you could consider adding a comment to the *question* stating something like

> I had posted an answer suggesting x earlier, but I was made aware by @user1 and @user2 that this won't solve the problem because....

Comment: YES! To quote/paraphrase myself: _"If an answer is incorrect and the original poster can't be bothered or isn't able to better the answer enough for it to be correct then the optimal solution that requires the least work from the community and moderators is that the poster self-deletes the answer."_ I originally wrote this for questions but it still fits. If it's wrong then there's no harm done in removing it.